# Fingerprint reader doesn't work after upgrade to WIN10 20H2

Tags: hp-pavilion, fingerprint

Problem: Fingerprint sensor doesn't have light/doesn't work/windows hello FP setup won't work.

What I've done:

- Installed new SSD but didn't copy any data from the old HDD (fresh WIN10 install).
- Watched this: [[FIX GUIDE] Enable Fingerprint Scanner HP Laptops Windows Hello](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HNtBX-LyiM), and several other videos.
- Installed drivers from HP - they didn't help (Validity Sensor) so I installed a synaptics driver (which I belive I had before).

[Synaptics FP Sensors WBF driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogJ55.png)

- Restarted several times of course
- Checked BIOS to see if a setting somehow got turned off

I tried to copy the whole DriverStore from my HDD to SSD but that failed.  Copying has been restricted, even with admin privledges.

Type of laptop: HP Pavilion m7-1015dx - 17.3" - Core i7 3610QM - 8 GB RAM

  
UPDATE: I found out how to backup & restore drivers using double driver, but after I backed them up on the HDD and SSD the SSD then blue-screened during the next boot with BCD corruption.  I never even got to the driver restore part of the process.  I had to waste most of a day doing a straight clone of the HDD.  Back in business but won't try again in the near future.

Comment: Get the HP Hardware Diagnostics app for your machine and run it. FP reader is a hardware test. Then if necessary contact HP Support.

Comment: @John The HP Hardware Diagnostics app doesn't have an option for FP reader testing and if you look up support info on their website they say that FP sensor testing is unavailable in the Windows version.

Comment: I would contact HP Support. My own systems (not HP) test the Fingerprint reader